# Is it safe to set auth 'Cookie' inside interceptor manually?

Tags: javascript, angular, http, cookies, angular-universal

In my angular application I have interceptor class like that:

```
import { Injectable, Inject, Optional, PLATFORM_ID } from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpInterceptor,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpRequest,
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { REQUEST } from '@nguniversal/express-engine/tokens';
import { isPlatformServer } from '@angular/common';
@Injectable()
export class UniversalInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(
    @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId,
    @Optional() @Inject(REQUEST) private request
  ) {}
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
    if (isPlatformServer(this.platformId)) {
      req = req.clone({ headers: req.headers.set('Cookie', this.request.headers.cookie) });
    }
    return next.handle(req);
  }
}
```

I am using Angular Universal server side rendering, so I take token from server and manually set in every API call which will be called by server. Everything works fine, but is it safe? I set token cookie manually inside every API request's header, maybe that's somehow risky?

Answer (score 0):

I mayb be wrong, but I think it only matters if you send cookies to an API that you don't own, in which case you might be sending sensitive information to a 3rd party.

If you don't own the API, you could try parsing the cookies string (`this.request.headers.cookie`) and only pass the ones that the API need